# Find the solutions of the differential equation $y\frac{dy}{dx}+\sqrt{x-xy^4}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solutions of the differential equation $y\frac{dy}{dx}+\sqrt{x-xy^4}=0$

Attempt: If $u=x-xy^4$ then $\frac{du}{dx}=1-(y^4+4xy^3\frac{dy}{dx})$ But I couldn't solve it from here. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Change $\sqrt{x-xy^4}$ to $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-y^4}$ and then apply separation of variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ y\frac{dy}{dx} + \sqrt x \sqrt{1-y^4} = 0 \\ y \frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt x \sqrt{1-y^4}\\ \int\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^4}}dy = - \int \sqrt x dx = -\frac23 x \sqrt x + C \\ \int \frac12\frac{d}{dy} \arcsin(y^2)dy = -\frac{2}{3}x\sqrt x + C \\  \arcsin(y^2) = -\frac43 x\sqrt x + C \\ y = \pm \sqrt{\sin\left(-\frac43 x\sqrt x + C \right)}$$

Comment: Do I have to put some restraints on $x$ and $y$, i.e. $x-xy^4 \geq 0$ and $x \geq 0$ so that it can be wrote as $\sqrt{x} \sqrt{1-y^4}$